# Pass Dynamic Value to Django url built-in

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Within a view, I am maintaining a dictionary containing some data I would like to display in an `<a>` in a template with [the Django `url` built-in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

*my_view.py*

```
links = [
  {
    'name': 'link 1',
    'pattern': 'fe:upload'
  },
  {
    'name': 'link 2',
    'pattern': 'fe:download'
  }
]
```

It will work hardcoded like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'fe:upload' id %}">up</a>
<a href="{% url 'fe:download' id %}">down</a>
```

However I'm struggling to put it into a loop

*my_template.html*

```
<ul>
  {% for link in links %}
    <li>
      <a href='{% url link.pattern id %}'>{{link.name}}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I have tried:

- escaping the quotations with `\` and HTML entities
- putting the href into a temp variable, eg: `{% with href=url 'link.pattern' %}` and get the error:

> `u'with' received an invalid token: u"'link.pattern'"`

#### how can I put a dynamic pattern into this loop to generate an anchor?

Comment: What error do you get with the original code?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm sorry, what do you mean with the original code? Which?

Comment: The one you show in my_template.html. You showed the error when you used `with`, but what happened before you did that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

```
{% with link.pattern as link_pattern %}
    <li>
      <a href='{% url link_pattern id %}'>{{link.name}}</a>
    </li>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: This seems to work! i thought that the `with something=something.else` was the same as the `with`/`as` pattern. How do they differ exactly? Thanks man!

Comment: Glad i could help!

Comment: I haven't used `with something=something.else` to be honest. I just remember that every time i need to have something dynamic inside a template tag i can just cast this **something** `as` a name variable which i can use inside.

Comment: Note, OP's problem was not `as` vs `=`, it was the bizarre use of `href=url 'something'`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman can you explain why that is bizarre? I’m new to the django landscape and I’ve inherited that bit. What would be more typical in your view?