# How to include dynamic data to django url template tag

Tags: django

Say i have a url in my template like this

```
`<a href="{% url 'dashboard:clinic:users' %}">users</a>`
```

Now in the aspect of clinic, it's not static but dynamic. That means it can also be like this:

```
`<a href="{% url 'dashboard:laboratory:users' %}">users</a>`
```

how can i include a variable inside the url template tag to replace clinic with the variable content.

Comment: I found a thread that worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54187320/pass-dynamic-value-to-django-url-built-in

Answer (score 0):

*Have you tryed this*

```
{% for each in list %}
    <li>
      <a href='{% url each.link %}'>{{each.name}}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```